# failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, wordpress, vagrant, virtualbox

i tried to activate the zibbra library.
the library and the adapter which i follow into the zibbra documentation
my folder path is like this
c:\xampp\htdocs\doorbraakboeken
and its seems that when i activate the library
this is what it goes

```
Warning: require_once(../api-client-library/php/library.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/doorbraak/templates/homepage.php on line 8

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../api-client-library/php/library.php' (include_path='/var/www/html/vendor') in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/doorbraak/templates/homepage.php on line 8
```

My code is written  inside doorbraakboeken.be/wp-content/themes/doorbraak/templates/homepage.php file this is my code below to call the library

```
<?php


    require_once("../api-client-library/php/library.php");
    require_once("../api-client-library/php/adapter/standalone");

    //Instantiate the adapter
    $adapter = new Zibbra_Adapter_Standalone();

    //Instantiate the library
    $library =  ZLibrary::getInstance($adapter);
    $library->setApiClientId("test client id");
    $library->setApiClientSecret("test client secret");

?>
```

This is my folder 
main folder `doorbraakboeken` inside folder is

```
api-client-library
doorbraakboeken.be
wordpress.zibbra.com
```

Im using windows and im using vagrant virtual box
Can someone help me figured this out to point correctly the path in order to load my library?
Any help is muchly appreciated. TIA

Comment: Try resolving to absolute paths ~ `require_once __DIR__ . '/../api-client-library/...';`

Comment: ok ill try your code

Comment: it seems this is what it throws 
Warning: require_once(/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/doorbraak/templates/../api-client-library/...): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/doorbraak/templates/homepage.php on line 10

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/doorbraak/templates/../api-client-library/...' (include_path='/var/www/html/vendor') in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/doorbraak/templates/homepage.php on line 10

Comment: I didn't mean literally `...`. It was just to show you how to prefix your paths with the current script directory with `__DIR__`. You would still need to include the files in your question by name

Comment: this one?
require_once __DIR__ . './api-client-library/php/library.php.';

Comment: more like `require_once __DIR__ . '/../api-client-library/php/library.php'; require_once __DIR__ . '/../api-client-library/php/adapter/standalone.php';`

Comment: oh its the same error tried your code hmmm

Comment: throws error
Warning: require_once(/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/doorbraak/templates/../api-client-library/php/library.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/doorbraak/templates/homepage.php on line 9

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/doorbraak/templates/../api-client-library/php/library.php' (include_path='/var/www/html/vendor') in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/doorbraak/templates/homepage.php on line 9

Comment: Simple, those files don't exist where you say they do. Good luck

Comment: ahh okay i see thanks that's what i really wanted to know if the files exists in vagrant cause it seems i have my files in my c:\xampp\htdocs\doorbraakboeken folder

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/relative/path/from_file";

//For You
require_once __DIR__ . "/doorbraakboeken/api-client-library/...upto_file_dest";
```

OR

Try by making below change:

change your DocumentRoot From "C:/xampp/htdocs" to Your project directory or wherever you want by configuring file C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf.

Comment: thanks i already solve this ... the problem is the path folder from vagrant is different from  my windows machine